# DateListPlot with Tooltip for a TimeSeries?

Tags: plotting, time-series

I would like to use `Tooltip` on a `TimeSeries` from within `DateListPlot` with a human readable date format (eg, "Mar 1, 2020") rather that `AbsoluteTime`. `Tooltip` works, but I've been unable to find a way to show anything other that `AbsoluteTime`. Is there a way to display a more human readable date?

Here is some example code:

```
vals = RandomReal[10, 10];
ts = TimeSeries[vals, {{2020, 3, 1}}];
DateListPlot[Tooltip@ts, Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Example Plot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateListPlot[Tooltip[#,
   {DateString[First @ #, { "MonthNameShort", "  ", "Day", " / ", "Year"}], 
    Last @ #}] & /@ ts["Path"], Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]